# How much content should an AngularJs Controller hold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Stack friends! Long time viewer, first time inquisitor!

I am a decently versed web designer. HTML5, CSS, jQuery, SCSS, (40% of the way through a Javascript learning program.) Grunt, Yeoman, Foundation, Bootstrap, Compass, etc...

Starting my first attempt at an Angular App. My only real question is...

How much content should my Controllers hold?

For instance,

```
    app.controller('ControllerNameHere', function ($scope) {
$scope.headerText = 'Header, Yall!';
$scope.introduction = 'Let me introduce myself. My name is Zack. This particular sentence could go on all night. Lets Lorem this a bit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tristique faucibus lectus id accumsan. Donec in eros id urna rutrum imperdiet nec in metus. Pellentesque faucibus, est vitae efficitur dapibus, lacus nisi sodales elit, eu sollicitudin lorem tellus vitae risus. Pellentesque iaculis orci id accumsan mattis. Duis sodales viverra nunc vitae laoreet. Aenean vitae nulla diam. Etiam semper condimentum diam. Quisque nec tincidunt massa. Aliquam varius eros in bibendum rhoncus. Ut sit amet blandit orci. Vestibulum enim nisl, mollis eleifend felis id, egestas hendrerit purus. Curabitur porta mauris ac orci sodales rhoncus.';
$scope.aSecondaryParagraph = 'Yes, I am a GEEEEE!';});
```

While 1 paragraph doesn't seem like too much, what if I was making a video game tutorial site? It could easily be 150+ paragraph tags' worth of info. Meaning all the text would be downloaded with "app.js" or whatever I load initially

Would this info be better placed statically within the views, or in the controllers for dynamic insertion?

Thanks for taking the time!
Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content should belong in your view, not in your controller. In Angular.js, the controller should primarily contain functions, dynamic content, models, etc -- things that you need in order to provide interactivity.

In contrast, static content such as your header, introduction, text, etc should be just HTML and belong in your view, unless you're genuinely dynamically generating all your content.

Remember, HTML is meant to hold content, CSS is meant to add style, and Javascript is meant to define behavior. The same thing applies with Angular.js.

Views hold content, Controllers help define behavior, Services contain logic that's independent of the view/any DOM manipulation, Directives bundle together related code/do DOM manipulation, and Filters help give your view a little more spice.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the application, at end of the day the client will have to load the the 150+ paragraph tags somewhere. Once loaded. both the JS and HTML templates get cached on the clients machine.

If the text is static and will never change - then it's probably best to keep it in the template just to keep things neat. However, if its going to change then its best to load it dynamically via AJAX.

Comment: In this particular application, the entirety of the content would not have to be loaded/viewed, rather portions. You do not want ALL wikipedia has to offer, just your specific criteria after all. But you do raise a valid observation. Depends on the application. Thanks for the contribution.